# Using grep for "and" instead of "or"

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of urls:

```
urls <- c("xx.zip", "zx.zip", "zz.rar")
```

I can find all the zip files like this:

```
zlst <- grep("zip", urls)
zls <- urls[zlst]
zls 
[1] "xx.zip" "zx.zip"
```

If i want to find all the files including "z" AND "zip", how do I do that. If it was "z" OR "zip" i could use |, but it doesn't work with &.

```
zlst <- grep("z&zip", urls)
zls <- urls[zlst]
zls

character(0)
```

Wanted output:

```
[1] "zx.zip"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the possible order of appearance. With just two strings, that's not a big deal:

```
grep("z.*zip|zip.*z", urls, value = TRUE)
# [1] "zx.zip"
```

There's no direct way of specifying a logical AND operator like the OR operator `|` in a single regex pattern afaik.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this +1

Comment: Actually, you _could_ simulate AND by doing two greps for the two patterns, then taking the intersection of the two outputs.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes of course that's possible. But that's obviously still not a direct AND condition

Comment: Also, thanks for the value = T, also good to trim the number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, match on starting (`^`) with `z` and ending (`$`) with `zip`:

```
grep("^z.*zip$", urls, value = TRUE)
# [1] "zx.zip"
```