# Is it possible to use an AND operator in grepl()?

Tags: r, logic, logical-operators, grepl

I want to search for anything that begins with `55` and anything that has the word `Roof` (case-sensitive, for those who are curious) in it.

So far I have been unsuccessful, as I can only seem to use the `OR` operator:

```
grepl("*^55|*Roof", dataset$longname)
```

Ultimately, I want to achieve something like this:

```
grepl("*^55&&*Roof", dataset$longname)
```

or

```
grepl("*^55&*Roof", dataset$longname)
```

(Clearly, neither of these work - they're for illustration only.)

I want my results to show anything that begins with `55` and which has the word `Roof` anywhere in it.

For example, I would expect both of these results to be picked up by the `grepl()` function:

```
55 - Roof Structure
```

and

```
55-Wall to Roof
```

Is there an `AND` operator that can be used with `grepl()`?

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187414/r-grep-is-there-an-and-operator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [r- grepl to find multiple strings exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152970/r-grepl-to-find-multiple-strings-exists)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To search for a string having both "a" and "b"

```
grepl("a", x) & grepl("b", x)
```

or

```
grepl("a.*b|b.*a", x)
```

If we know the order of the two parts then we can omit one of the two halves of the last `grepl`.  For example, in the case of the query in the question this would be sufficient to find a string that starts with 55 and contains Roof

```
grepl("^55.*Roof", x)
```

Another possibility is

```
grep("a.*b", paste(x, x))
```

If the terms searched for have space then use a different `sep=` in `paste`.

Comment: Perfect!  The second option works best for me as I like to keep my code as clean and concise as possible.  I opted for: `grepl("*^55.*Roof", dataset$longname)` Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to include multiple `AND`s, or is that where your first example comes in?  For example, can I do `grepl("*55.*Roof.*TOS", dataset$longname)`?  I have tried and it doesn't return any results, so am guessing not.

Comment: If you know the order you can do use `a.*b.*c` but if not you could either use multiple `grepl` commands `grepl(...) & grepl(...) & grepl(...)` or else use `a.*b.*c|a.*c.*b|b.*a.*c|b.*a.*c|c.*a.*b|c.*b.*a` .

Comment: I see, so `grepl()` works linearly in that it only finds the search terms in order/sequence, correct?

Comment: @SnookerFan: For a third option, using positive look-ahead, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152970/r-grepl-to-find-multiple-strings-exists/44153507#44153507.

Answer (score 6):

I am reposting an answer by @Psidom as his was deleted but was scalable to n AND clauses.  If @Psidom undeletes his response I will delete this one (I voted to undelete) but feel the answer is important for other searchers:

```
s <- c("55 - Roof Structure", "55-Wall to Roof", 'd 55 Roof')
grepl("(?=.*^55)^Roof", s, perl = TRUE)
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

## 2 AND clauses
grepl("^(?=.*^55)(?=.*Roof)(?=.*Wall)", s, perl = TRUE)
## [1]  FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```