# r - grepl matches with perl and spaces

Tags: r, regex, perl

this example from here ([r- grepl to find multiple strings exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152970/r-grepl-to-find-multiple-strings-exists/44153507))  helps me match combinations of words:

```
pat <- c("instance", "percentage", "element", "character")

longperl <- grepl(paste0("(?=.*", pat, ")", collapse=""), Text2, perl=TRUE)
```

However I'm trying to match the word `table` (along with other words) and using the above is also returning words that contain the pattern `table`, e.g., `marketable`. 
How do I force the grepl snippet to only include the whole word `table` and not where `table` is part of another word?

I've tried these without success:

```
pat <- c(" table", "instance", "percentage", "element", "character") # add literal space before `table`

pat <- c("\\stable", "instance", "percentage", "element", "character") # add whitespace regex before `table`
```

Comment: add word boundaries...? (`\\b table \\b`)